# Libgdx Dialog buttons cannot be clicked

Tags: input, libgdx, dialog

I have trouble properly implementing a dialog. It does not recognize button clicks - even the button down animation does not happen. However, it does recognize key presses (e.g. enter or esc in my case). Dialog does appear to be on top of the stage objects, so I'm confused why it isn't registering my clicks.

I have an InputMultiplexer with processors InputHandler class (implements InputProcessor) and stage, in that order:

```
InputMultiplexer im = new InputMultiplexer();
im.addProcessor(new InputHandler(stage));
im.addProcessor(stage);//trying to make dialog work by doing this
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(im);
```

Here's my showDialog method defined in stage:

```
public void showDialog() {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog("Quit?", skin) {

        @Override
        protected void result(Object object) {
            boolean exit = (Boolean) object;
            if (exit) {
                Gdx.app.exit();
            } else {
                remove();
            }
        }

    };
    dialog.button("Yes", true);
    dialog.button("No", false);
    dialog.key(Input.Keys.ENTER, true);
    dialog.key(Input.Keys.ESCAPE, false);
    dialog.show(this);
}
```

The showDialog() method is called from InputHandler when it recognizes that the game is over (I have it set so that the game state is checked and updated on touch up, since it's a touch based game). My understanding is that since the multiplexer receives false return from the InputHandler methods when the game is over, it then goes to the stage for input, which seems to be working only when I use key presses on the dialog, i.e. enter quits the game, esc removes the dialog, but clicking the buttons do nothing.

Here is my Screen's render function in case it's relevant:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
    Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
    Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | (Gdx.graphics.getBufferFormat().coverageSampling?GL20.GL_COVERAGE_BUFFER_BIT_NV:0));
    stage.act();
    stage.getCamera().update();
    stage.draw();
}
```

Comment: I don't know what's wrong, but consider trying to follow [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33069563/201891) _in a new project_ to confirm that it's working, then adapt your code to fit.

Comment: @DavidS Thanks for your advice. I have tested my dialog implementation in a blank project and confirmed that it was working, the only difference being that my game's dialog pops up when game is over. After some debugging I found that when the dialog is popped up, in the blank project I can click on anything other than the button and InputHandler's touchDown method is not called, but in my original project it calls the method despite the dialog. In both projects my stage's touchDown methods are not overriden, if that matters.

Comment: It could be something silly like another actor is over your button, or another stage is handling your touch events.

Comment: Are you sure that you are adding the dialog to the stage that has the input processor?