# LibGDX How to create message box with Java?

Tags: java, libgdx, messagebox

Im interested in how to create message box where the program can send messages like: 
"You got 50 damage", "You found a loot" etc. and user can see it? Just like Sout works in console but in UI (would be nice to use scrollpane for it). Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062574/how-to-properly-implement-a-dialog-box-using-libgdx

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you tu use the API VisUI for libGDX: https://github.com/kotcrab/vis-editor/wiki/VisUI. I draw all my GUI with it, is very easy to use.
[image: example]

Comment: Thx, i've already found a solution to make a list with scrollpane and simply add there Labels with text