# How to implement Dialog in LibGDX (unable to load skin)

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I want to implement a simple dialog box using the Dialog class. I tried using the standard skin files provided here

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data

- uiskin.atlas
- uiskin.json
- uiskin.png
- default.png
- default.fnt

I downloaded RAWs and I can't make them work.

The first line in json:

```
{BitmapFont: { default-font: { file: default.fnt } },
```

throws an error:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.reflect.ReflectionException: Class not found: BitmapFont
```

and the whole file in android studio is highlighted in red saying it doesn't conform to language specifications.

I loaded another file formatted like this:

```
{
  "com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont": {
    "default-font": {
      "file": "default.fnt"
    }
  },
  "com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color": {
    "green": {
      "a": 1,
      "b": 0,
      "g": 1,
      "r": 0
    },
    "white": {
      "a": 1,
      "b": 1,
      "g": 1,
      "r": 1
    },
    "red": {
      "a": 1,
      "b": 0,
      "g": 0,
      "r": 1
    },
    "black": {
      "a": 1,
      "b": 0,
      "g": 0,
      "r": 0
    }
  },
  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$TintedDrawable": {
    "dialogDim": {
      "name": "white",
      "color": {
        "r": 0,
        "g": 0,
        "b": 0,
        "a": 0.45
      }
    }
  },
  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button$ButtonStyle": {
    "default": {
      "down": "default-round-down",
      "up": "default-round"
    },
    "toggle": {
      "down": "default-round-down",
      "checked": "default-round-down",
      "up": "default-round"
    }
  },
  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle": {
    "default": {
      "down": "default-round-down",
      "up": "default-round",
      "font": "default-font",
      "fontColor": "white"
    },
    "toggle": {
      "down": "default-round-down",
      "up": "default-round",
      "checked": "default-round-down",
      "font": "default-font",
      "fontColor": "white",
      "downFontColor": "red"
    }
  },
  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ScrollPane$ScrollPaneStyle": {
    "default": {
      "vScroll": "default-scroll",
      "hScrollKnob": "default-round-large",
      "background": "default-rect",
      "hScroll": "default-scroll",
      "vScrollKnob": "default-round-large"
    }
  },
  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.SelectBox$SelectBoxStyle": {
    "default": {
      "font": "default-font",
      "fontColor": "white",
      "background": "default-select",
      "scrollStyle": "default",
      "listStyle": {
        "font": "default-font",
        "selection": "default-select-selection"
      }
    }
  },
  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.SplitPane$SplitPaneStyle": {
    "default-vertical": {
      "handle": "default-splitpane-vertical"
    },
    "default-horizontal": {
      "handle": "default-splitpane"
    }
  },
  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Window$WindowStyle": {
    "default": {
      "titleFont": "default-font",
      "background": "default-window",
      "titleFontColor": "white"
    },
    "dialog": {
      "titleFont": "default-font",
      "background": "default-window",
      "titleFontColor": "white",
      "stageBackground": "dialogDim"
    }
  },
  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ProgressBar$ProgressBarStyle": {
    "default-horizontal": {
      "background": "default-slider",
      "knob": "default-slider-knob"
    },
    "default-vertical": {
      "background": "default-slider",
      "knob": "default-round-large"
    }
  },
  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Slider$SliderStyle": {
    "default-horizontal": {
      "background": "default-slider",
      "knob": "default-slider-knob"
    },
    "default-vertical": {
      "background": "default-slider",
      "knob": "default-round-large"
    }
  },
  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle": {
    "default": {
      "font": "default-font",
      "fontColor": "white"
    }
  },
  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextField$TextFieldStyle": {
    "default": {
      "selection": "selection",
      "background": "textfield",
      "font": "default-font",
      "fontColor": "white",
      "cursor": "cursor"
    }
  },
  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.CheckBox$CheckBoxStyle": {
    "default": {
      "checkboxOn": "check-on",
      "checkboxOff": "check-off",
      "font": "default-font",
      "fontColor": "white"
    }
  },
  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.List$ListStyle": {
    "default": {
      "fontColorUnselected": "white",
      "selection": "selection",
      "fontColorSelected": "white",
      "font": "default-font"
    }
  },
  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Touchpad$TouchpadStyle": {
    "default": {
      "background": "default-pane",
      "knob": "default-round-large"
    }
  },
  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Tree$TreeStyle": {
    "default": {
      "minus": "tree-minus",
      "plus": "tree-plus",
      "selection": "default-select-selection"
    }
  },
  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextTooltip$TextTooltipStyle": {
    "default": {
      "label": {
        "font": "default-font",
        "fontColor": "white"
      },
      "background": "default-pane",
      "wrapWidth": 150
    }
  }
}
```

and i got another error:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: 
No Drawable, NinePatch, TextureRegion, Texture, or Sprite registered with name: white
```

Does anyone know about a working skin pack that i can just download and it will work?

Comment: This post will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33069563/6742601

Comment: Didn't test it, but the file looks fine, probably red because the IDE support this file.

Answer (score 0):

In first case :

> {BitmapFont: { default-font: { file: default.fnt } },

you need to use fully qualified Java class name like 
`"com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont"`

In second case : You've missing something in `.json` like not able to find resource(`white`)

---

Look at [this](https://github.com/czyzby/gdx-skins) repository, containing number of free LibGDX Scene2D GUI skins.